# How do I add keys to values in an Array of Arrays?

Tags: arrays, key-pair

I have an Array of Arrays as follows:

```
[ "Martin", 49 ],
[ "Klaas", 39 ],
[ "Piet", 39 ],
[ "Henk", 44 ]
]
```

I would like to add key-labels to my existing values so that it will look like this:

```
[ 
[ name: "Martin", age: 49 ],
[ name: "Klaas", age: 39 ],
[ name: "Piet", age: 39 ],
[ name: "Henk", age: 44 ]
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd array since it is a key value pair, It should be dict type. You can achieve that using this,

```
array = [
    [ "Martin", 49 ],
    [ "Klaas", 39 ],
    [ "Piet", 39 ],
    [ "Henk", 44 ]
]

result_array = [{'name' : value[0], 'age': value[1]} for value in array]

print(result_array)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Martin', 'age': 49}, {'name': 'Klaas', 'age': 39}, {'name': 'Piet', 'age': 39}, {'name': 'Henk', 'age': 44}]
```

Comment: that results in an SyntaxError:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Can't get the finger behind where that ] should be....

Comment: please copy paste once again. It is running fine.

Comment: That missing bracket in your question section.

Comment: this is my interpretation of your solution:
```
let listOfCountries = [{'country' : value[0], 'count': value[1]} for value in countries];
```

but it still results in the error: missing ] after element list.